# Convert XML to HTML Table in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform my XML to an HTML table but still quite confused with how to do row-column mapping using templates. My XML definition is:

```
<Table>
  <Parent>
    <Head>Header 1</Head>
    <Children>
      <Node>Node 1</Node>
      <Node>Node 2</Node>
      <Node>Node 3</Node>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Head>Header 2</Head>
    <Children>
      <Node>Node 4</Node>
      <Node>Node 5</Node>
      <Node>Node 6</Node>
    </Children>
  </Parent>
</Table>
```

**Expected HTML output:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Header 1</td>
    <td>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Node 1</td>
    <td>Node 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Node 2</td>
    <td>Node 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Node 3</td>
    <td>Node 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've used template matching but can't figure out how to do the mapping by position. This is my current XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent"/>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent/Children"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="Head"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent/Children">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent/Children/Node">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume each `Parent` has the same number of nodes, you can start off by selecting just the nodes of the first Parent, as these will then represent the start of each new row

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Parent[1]/Children/Node" mode="row"/>
```

(The `mode` is used here, because the final XSLT will have multiple templates matching `Node`)

Then, for the template that matches these nodes, you create a new table row, and copy in the child nodes from all parents that in the same position in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Node" mode="row">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../../../Parent/Children/Node[position() = current()/position()]" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent"/>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent[1]/Children/Node" mode="row"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="Head"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node" mode="row">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../../Parent/Children/Node[position() = $pos]" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim C. If the rows are not equal (say, the 2nd Parent has more items than the first), should I use Muenchian grouping to handle it?

Comment: You would need to locate the parent with the most children  rather than just pick the first parent.  It might be easier to ask a whole new follow-up question. Thanks!

Comment: Or, maybe this helps... http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6C